# prism:ClearChildViewsRegionBehavior.ClearChildViews="True" not clearing ChildViews

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-4

I have following region hierarchy.

MainRegion
----SubRegionA

MainRegion has SubRegionA. I load view in SubRegionA through Navigation. The views get loaded correctly. When I re-navigate to MainRegion and subsequently to SubRegionA, I still get the old views of SubRegionA that were loaded previously. What I wanted was that when I re-navigate to SubRegionA, all the views in the SubRegionA should be cleared from memmory and fresh views should be loaded. But prism is still holding references to those views and loading them when I re-navigate to SubRegionA. I tried to place the following on the MainRegion and SubRegionA declaration but that didn't solve the issue.

**MainRegion**

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static g:RegionNames.MainRegion}"
                prism:ClearChildViewsRegionBehavior.ClearChildViews="True"/>
```

**SubRegionA**

```
        <TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static g:RegionNames.SubRegionA}"
                    prism:ClearChildViewsRegionBehavior.ClearChildViews="True"
                    Style="{StaticResource TabStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemContainerStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" />
```

In short, when a region is NavigatedFrom(removed), how do we clear(from memmory) all views from this region, and all the nested regions that this region contains.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try IRegionMemberLifetime Interface?

```
bool KeepAlive { get{return False;} }
```